# fast interacting with large number of elements inside a container (DOM, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have a large number of divs (4000-5000) [each contains spans, anchors, images etc.] inside a container div and basically I am setting their display to none or block based on a condition. This does take some time.

In my search for something faster I came across this page https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom and the solution there is to remove the container div from the DOM and iterate the contained elements by getElementsByTagName.

```
/**
 * Remove an element and provide a function that inserts it into its original position
 * @param element {Element} The element to be temporarily removed
 * @return {Function} A function that inserts the element into its original position
 **/
function removeToInsertLater(element) {
  var parentNode = element.parentNode;
  var nextSibling = element.nextSibling;
  parentNode.removeChild(element);
  return function() {
    if (nextSibling) {
      parentNode.insertBefore(element, nextSibling);
    } else {
      parentNode.appendChild(element);
    }
  };
}


function updateAllAnchors(element, anchorClass) {
  var insertFunction = removeToInsertLater(element);
  var anchors = element.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i ++) {
    anchors[i].className = anchorClass;
  }
  insertFunction();
}
```

The problem is I cannot use the solution provided because I need to access the children elements by their IDs and I can't do that, since the elements are removed from the DOM. Is there any way to achieve this?

I also tried to remove the container div and append it to a documentfragment, but still I can't access the 5000 elements by their ID when they are in the documentfragment

Finally, I also tried this:

```
document.getElementById("CONTAINERDIV").style.display = "none";

//iterate through the 5000 children divs and change their classname

document.getElementById("CONTAINERDIV").style.display = "block";
```

because I was hoping that it would not trigger a reflow for each iteration, but this didn't seem to provide an improvement in the time required.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: You say setting the style for the single element didn't provide any improvement in time required – but did the first option? I'd be very surprised if setting the display attribute of one container is faster than removing it and then reinserting it. Have you got a test case jsFiddle or somesuch to play with?

Comment: Another aside: I assume switching the classname of every anchor is just a simplified example of the kind of very performance-expensive DOM operations you're performing, but it is an incredibly wasteful one too: view processors like [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) attempt to hyper-optimize DOM interactions, but in a case like this you may consider changing your application such that you do not need to make such expensive modifications. Can you give us examples of the actual modifications you're making?

Comment: you can use querySelectorAll("#idofelement") to get off-dom nodes by ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display none/block is expensive. From my days of improving performance on trading web platforms, one technique I can recommend that'll shine especially with older browsers is to use position relative and yank it off the screen using a negative left value. Of course depending on your implementation, you might want to set the height to 0px as well or look into possibilities with position absolute. The core concept still remains that you are simply yanking the element off the screen. Good news is that the elements hidden are still in the DOM and you can access them.

```
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
div.hide {
  left: -4096px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Check out these two fiddles, they create 10K rows and toggle(hide/show) the odd rows:

[FIDDLE using Display none/block](http://jsfiddle.net/QCxGL/)

[FIDDLE using Position and Height](http://jsfiddle.net/np9LS/)

Chrome handles 100K of these rows in a snap and it's difficult to see a significant performance improvement, whereas for Firefox I had to reduce the row count to 10K and the performance gain  is much more apparent.

Comment: @chayram I tried your method but with proper classes it's very slow... check here http://jsfiddle.net/np9LS/2/

Answer (score 9):

I will try to provide sources as requested.

**First solution** - ***best one***
According to this site: [JavaScript Grid with One Million Records](http://w2ui.com/web/blog/7/JavaScript-Grid-with-One-Million-Records)
You can learn several important things:

1. Large number of DOM nodes make rendering slow
2. JavaScript arrays can handle large data sets
3. Looping through large arrays is fast
4. Sorting arrays by providing custom function to Array.sort() is fast
5. eval() is slow, should not be used in large loops

So, I would recommend you to build an array to handle in a fast way your elements.

**Second solution**
Another solution taken from this site: [Processing large amounts of data in JavaScript](http://lamosty.com/2013/02/05/processing-large-amounts-of-data-in-javascript/)
would be to use a timeout (as strange as it sounds) to increase speed of handler. 
The idea comes from [Book: Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/)

Comment: I agree with this guy, this is exactly what I did in one project where can be +100k elements. You can also combinate both solutions, array for logic + save elements and setTimeout for attaching/detaching elements from DOM.

Comment: @Elfentech I edited your solution because I think it is the best and I was to lazy doing my own while we share same ideas. Accept it only if you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you want only to show/hide, without change anything in the div's DOM and you know all the IDs, I think, that the best (fastest) way to archive this would be to prepare `<style />` element and append it to DOM. Style el should contain all the ID's and proper display. Iterate through IDs and add it to CSS string, then create `<style />` element and append string to it. This should work for you.

Comment: I like your solution, very clever, will try it and give you feedback, the only problem i have, is that it is kind of hack-ish

Answer (score 4):

Build an id-to-element map / hash table beforehand:

```
var map = {};

for (var i = 0, l = ids.length; i < l; i++) {
    map[ids[i]] = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
}
```

where `ids` is a list of element IDs. (If you need to 5000 elements by their IDs, I assume you have a list or can generate one.)

Then when you remove the container element from the DOM, you can use the map to find elements by their IDs.

Comment: @MirrorMirror were you able to try this approach?

Comment: I've not been online for a couple of days. will try it and give feedback :), thank you

Answer (score 3):

The following two statements are equivalent (the second approach requires the `#` but is available on all elements, not just the document).

```
elt = document.getElementById("theId");
elt = document.querySelector("#theId");
```

So you can use `element.querySelector('#theId')` to get to a child element based on its ID (even if the parent `element` is currently detached from DOM).

Note that [querySelector() is not supported in IE 7](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) and older.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I will test this and give my feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide or show all elements, why not let css do it for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/M3gye/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggle_divs();" value="Toggle"/>
<div id="container1">
    <div id="div1" class="border">div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="border">div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="border">div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="border">div4</div>
    <div id="div5" class="border">div5</div>
    <div id="div6" class="border">div6</div>
    <div id="div7" class="border">div7</div>
    <div id="div8" class="border">div8</div>
    <div id="div9" class="border">div9</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.hide div {
    display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function toggle_divs() {
    var d = document.getElementById('container1');
    if (d) {
        if (d.className == "hide")
            d.className = "";
        else
            d.className = "hide";
    }
}
```

In this example, all I do is set the class of the container div and let the selectors to the rest for me.

Comment: no you misunderstood. I don't hide all divs, only some of them

Comment: well, in that case, I'm not sure it'll help but a while ago I wrote a script that iterated over 700 element to look for a matching text. It worked very fast even in IE7 that was the slowest browser I had to adapt to at the time. It based on two containers: an empty one for display and a hidden one as a repository that held all of the elements.

Comment: **continue:** Every new search I emptied the display container (`displayDiv.innerHTML = ''` did the trick) and then went through the elements in the repository, looking for any match and adding it to the display (`displayDiv.appendChild(repositoryDiv.children[#].cloneNode(true))`). All of this worked surprisingly fast but I never tried it for thousands of element so I don't know how well it will be compared to other suggestions.