# Page is freezing with tabs when having a list with too many dom elements

Tags: html, css, dom, optimization, responsive-design

I have a web page with two columns, a header with a navigation bar and a footer.

The left column is used to listing items in three different tabs. Each tab contains its items' type.

The right side contains one or more maps to display the items.

The problem occurs when selecting a tab that contains too many elements.

It freezes the interaction (highlights, adding/removing DOM and animations), breaking its responsiveness.

Even when it isn't an interaction with the selected tab (i.e. mouse hover on a navigation bar link).

But the page's responsiveness is fine when the selected tab has fewer items.

I created a [**spike solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/jonibatista/fwf1v16o/7/) to show you what I'm saying.

**Please, you should keep in mind that this is a much simpler version of my problem. It's just a dummy example to present my case.**

```js
$('#nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});

$('#addBox').on('click', function () {
  $("#content").append("<div class='box pull-left'></div>");
});

$('#newPapper').on('click', function () {
  $("#content").empty();
});


$('#addOne').on('click', function () {
  $("#home div.panel-default").append(createContactDom());
});

$('#addThousand').on('click', function () {
  var dom = "";
  for(var i = 5000; i > 0; i--){
    dom+=createContactDom();
  }
  $("#home div.panel-default").append(dom);
});

$('#clean').on('click', function () {
  $("#home div.panel-default").empty();
});

function createContactDom(){

  var age = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
  var birthday = moment().subtract(age, 'years');
  var isFemale = Math.random() > 0.4;
  var nameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names[isFemale ? "female" : "male"].length);
  var surnameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * surnames.length)
  var name = names[isFemale ? "female" : "male"][nameIndex] + " " + surnames[surnameIndex];
  
  var html = '<div id="p' + birthday.format("X") + '" class="panel-heading">';
  html += '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg custom-stack pull-left font-grey-gallery" >';
  html += '<i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>';
  html += '<i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x"></i>';
  html += '</span>';
  html += '<div class="pull-left">';
  html += '<div class="title">';
  html += '<span >' + name + '</span> ';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="sub-title">';
  html += '<span title="' + (isFemale ? 'She': 'He') + ' was born on a ' + birthday.format('dddd') + ' at ' + birthday.format('HH:MM a') + '" class="badge pull-left" >' + birthday.format("YYYY/MM/DD") +'</span>';
  html += '<span title="It is a ' + (isFemale ? 'female' : 'male') + '" class="badge pull-left ' + (isFemale ? 'female' : 'male') + '" >' + (isFemale ? 'Female' : 'Male') + '</span>';
  html += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="pull-right actions">';
  html += '<a id="d' + birthday.format("X") + '" title="Delete contact" class="fa fa-times fa-times-close"  style="color: rgb(87, 142, 190);" onclick="deleteContact(this)"></a>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
  html += '</div>';
  
 return html;                      
}


deleteContact = function(e){
  $("#" + e.id.replace("d", "p")).remove();
}

var names = {
  female: ["Maria","Leonor","Matilde","Beatriz","Carolina","Mariana","Ana","Inês","Margarida","Sofia"],
  male: ["João", "Martim", "Rodrigo", "Santiago", "Francisco", "Afonso", "Tomás", "Miguel", "Guilherme", "Gabriel"]
}
var surnames = ["Silva", "Santos", "Ferreira", "Pereira", "Oliveira", "Costa", "Rodrigues", "Martins", "Jesus", "Sousa", "Fernandes", "Gonçalves", "Gomes", "Lopes", "Marques", "Alves", "Almeida", "Ribeiro", "Pinto", "Carvalho"]
```

```css
.row{
  height: 600px;
}

.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-7{
  height: inherit;
}

.tab-content{
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;  
}

button{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
span.badge{
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.badge{
   background-color: #999 !important;
}
.badge.female{
   background-color: pink !important;
}
.badge.male{
   background-color: #1c90f3 !important;
}

#content{
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;  
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#content .box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist"> 
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Contacts</a>
      </li> 
      <li role="presentation" class="">
        <a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-expanded="false">Problem?</a>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <button type="button" id="addOne" class="btn btn-sm">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="addThousand" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">+5k</button>
        <button type="button" id="clean" class="btn btn-sm">clean</button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent"> 
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" role="tabpanel" id="home" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-left: 3px solid rgb(87, 142, 190);" >
        </div> 
      </div> 
         
      <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="profile" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"> 
        <h1>Problems to solve:</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Adding 5k new contacts blocks the browser's page</li>
          <li>Switching between the two tabs blocks the browser's page</li>
          <li>Painting freezes when adding 5k new contacts</li>
        </ul> 
        <p>Note: The problems get worse as may contacts you add...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <button tyoe="button" id="addBox" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Paint</button>
    <button tyoe="button" id="newPapper" class="btn btn-sm">New papper</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

I'm already using the chrome developer tools to capture the timeline's actions. As far I can see, the problem is some reflows in the layout rendering from jquery.

Here is a screenshot from my timeline:
[image]

How can I optimize my DOM manipulation in order to avoid page freezing? Can I tell Browser to not redraw left column until I say so?

Comment: How about starting by NOT using 5000 moment to calculate birthday? Instead use ONE moment when the user mouses over the date

Comment: As I said, this was just a dummy sample to exemplify my problem. My real problem just shares the page's layout scheme (header with a navigation bar, two columns, and a footer)

Comment: all elements are almost added to the dom simultaneously, you could try to replace your for loop with setTimeout or setInterval or a recursive function, to have some delay

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use **virtual scroll** or **infinite scroll** or **pagination** for such a big table, instead of creating it on startup?

There are many example:
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Putting 5k objects in one line is too much, imo.

In your case, you will need to split/interrupt dom manipulation loop for other stuff in stack/event loop.

```
$('#addThousand').on('click', function () {
  for(var i = 5000; i > 0; i--){
  setTimeout( function() {
    var dom=createContactDom();
    $("#home div.panel-default").append(dom);
    }, 0);
  }

});
```

Or event that:

```
$('#addThousand').on('click', function () {
  for(var i = 5000; i > 0; i--){
  setTimeout( function() {
    var dom=createContactDom();
    $("#home div.panel-default").append(dom);
    }, i);
  }

});
```

Comment: As I said before, the example it's just for presenting my problem. In my real problem, I have like 300 o 600 items. The problem isn't the time that takes to load the items but the time that takes to switching between tabs when having too many elements...

Comment: This solution can resolve your problem too. Load only the first 20 contact on each tab and load 10 by 10 more contact on scroll down.

Comment: @jbatista actually his answer is applicable in your case. yes javascript can load it all under a second.. but notifying every element to adjust theirselves all at once is different and that is where your browser freezes. hope it makes sense

Comment: @jbatista when you switching between tabs, you probably repopulate the whole list of elements to dom by explicitly/implicitly applying "display:none"? Cannot you then use visibility hidden instead?

Comment: Paul and Alexis, let's imagine that I do that. Then after 500 scrolls, I get the 5000 contacts. If I tried to change between tabs it'll take to many time again... Even better, after 5000 contacts I stop adding more (5000 is the limit). Then I start playing with painting in the right column. It still freezes... If you don't see it with 5000 try with 10 000 or more. Again, it's just a dummy example, in my real problem this happens with less than 500 items. Andrey, that is my best guess... Probably I need to implement my own tabs as @Seabizkit said in another thread.

Comment: @jbatista what you said is only true for **infinite scroll**. Virtual scroll and pagination will always be limited by number of displayed items.

Answer (score 3):

[fast interacting with large number of elements inside a container (DOM, javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195771/fast-interacting-with-large-number-of-elements-inside-a-container-dom-javascri)

yes i did do some testing and research... which lead me to this.

u need to use something like the below. The issue is display none and block have an impact on the dom performance based on the mount of data you are hiding/showing.

The way to get around this...is to just shift it out of view. this way the dom does not have to run calcs on if the content is there or not.. as it technically has never left doing it this way. Down side is you would need to implement your own tabs.. soda speak to be able to override the default behavior.

```
div {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
div.hide {
  left: -4096px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would brain storm different way to display the data so that this doesn't rely on such heavy dom lifting

Comment: This didn't solve my main problem (page freezes when the selected tab has a big list of items making highlights, adding/removing DOM and animations to expensive). Although I notice that with this kind of implementation it's faster to switch between tabs. For that reason and since the bounty is almost expering I give you the points. Thanks for trying to help :)